# Grab value from input field on SHAREPOINT INFOPATH browser enabled form

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to get the value of a textbox into a JavaScript variable. ultimately I'm trying to hide or show different webparts depending on the value in the textbox. I'm piecing the code together to test for input first. Below is the code for the textbox in question that I pulled from Firebug:

```
<input onfocus="return (TextBox.OnFocus(this, event));" onblur="return (TextBox.OnBlur(this, event));" oninput="return  (TextBox.OnInput(this, event));" id="ctl00_m_g_ff1af521_db80_4f46_9a65_42671828173f_FormControl0_V1_I1_T82" scriptclass="TextBox" class="z_VYBB68eomwymAKXW_0 c5_VYBB68eomwymAKXW_0 ef_VYBB68eomwymAKXW_0" wrapped="true" direction="ltr" viewdatanode="83" formid="ctl00_m_g_ff1af521_db80_4f46_9a65_42671828173f_FormControl0" originalid="V1_I1_T82" tabindex="0" title="" value="Visible" style="position: relative;" type="text">
```

If I use the code below I get an "Undefined" error message(popup). As you can clearly see though, the value of the textbox = "Visible" as the code above tells us.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var HideWeb = $("#ctl00_m_g_ff1af521_db80_4f46_9a65_42671828173f_FormControl0_V1_I1_T82").val();
    alert(HideWeb);
});
```

I've also tried the following with no success (popup returns empty).

```
var HideWeb = document.getElementById("#ctl00_m_g_ff1af521_db80_4f46_9a65_42671828173f_FormControl0_V1_I1_T82").value;
    alert(HideWeb);
```

I've also tried using the other ID numbers in hopes that one of them would work in the JavaScript\Jquery code above. If someone could pick this apart and help me determine what the problem is I would appreciate it.Thank you.

This correspondes to a question I asked here.......
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113969/showing-hiding-webparts-conditionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try..

```
$("input:text[originalid='V1_I1_T82']").val()
```

This will return you the value..

Answer (score 0):

try removing "#"

```
var HideWeb = $("ctl00_m_g_ff1af521_db80_4f46_9a65_42671828173f_FormControl0_V1_I1_T82").val();
```