# Hide element based on value of other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a table based on the value of two fields, so that if `field2` is equal to `field1` the table is hidden.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gh812x8/)

HTML:

```
<form>
    Expected Number of Items: <input type="text" value="14" name="totalItems" id="totalItems">
    <p>
    Number of Items Entered: <input type="text" value="14" name="enteredItems" id="enteredItems">
</form> 
<p>
<table border="1" style="width:100%" id="hideThis">
  <tr>
    <td>This should be hidden when "totalItems" equals "enteredItems"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function toggleClass(eid, myclass){
    var theEle = document.getElementById(eid);
    var eClass = theEle.className;

    if(eClass.indexOf(myclass) >= 0){
        theEle.className = eClass.replace(myclass, "");
    }else{
        theEle.className  += "" +myclass;
    }
}
```

Comment: address the issue clearly

Comment: The JSFiddle he provided uses jQuery

Comment: Sorry, this may be a dumb question. but do I not need jQuery to do this?

Comment: Generally speaking you don't *need* jQuery for anything. Anything you can achieve with jQuery can also be done in plain JavaScript. However jQuery does make a lot of things much easier.

Comment: You don't necessarily **need** jQuery, it just makes things easier, in many cases. I've added a non-jQuery implementation in my answer, if you want to get an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#totalItems, #enteredItems').keyup(function(){
        if( $('#totalItems').val() == $('#enteredItems').val() ){
            $('#hideThis').hide();
        }else{
            $('#hideThis').show();
        }
    });    
});
```

If you need to check also at page load:

```
function checkFields(){
    if( $('#totalItems').val() == $('#enteredItems').val() ){
        $('#hideThis').hide();
    }else{
        $('#hideThis').show();
    }
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#totalItems, #enteredItems').keyup(function(){
        checkFields();
    });   
    checkFields();
});
```

Plain JavaScript implementation:

```
function checkFields(){
    if(  document.getElementById('totalItems').value == document.getElementById('enteredItems').value ){
        document.getElementById('hideThis').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('hideThis').style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
}

document.getElementById('totalItems').addEventListener('keyup', function (){
   checkFields();
}, false);

document.getElementById('enteredItems').addEventListener('keyup', function (){
   checkFields();
}, false);

checkFields();
```

Comment: Well I thought I got this to work, however it appears to be hiding the table (web part) always. It may be a typo on my end. I will let you know.

Comment: I've tested each one of the three solutions I proposed in the JSFiddle you provided, replacing all the JavaScript code

Comment: I tried tweaking your code after reading [a related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064535/grab-value-from-input-field-on-sharepoint-infopath-browser-enabled-form). I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JFlattery/2oj20f2m/). However it still doesn't work :-/

Comment: @JamesFlattery please complete the JSFiddle you linked with your html

Answer (score 3):

See the comments in the code.

```js
// Function to hide/show the table based on the values of inputs
function toggleTable() {

  // Hides the table if the values of both input are same
  $('#hideThis').toggle($('#totalItems').val() !== $('#enteredItems').val());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Bind the keyup event on both the inputs, call the function on event
  $('#totalItems, #enteredItems').on('keyup', toggleTable).trigger('keyup');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>Expected Number of Items:
  <input type="text" value="14" name="totalItems" id="totalItems">
  <p>Number of Items Entered:
    <input type="text" value="14" name="enteredItems" id="enteredItems">
</form>
<p>
  <table border="1" style="width:100%" id="hideThis">
    <tr>
      <td>This should be hidden when "totalItems" equals "enteredItems"</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3gh812x8/5/)

Comment: Will toggleTable work with other types of elements besides tables? Ultimately I am trying to hide a SharePoint web part.

Comment: @JamesFlattery It's custom function, you can modify it however you want. I think it should work in SharePoint too

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sence.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a keyup events for both the text boxes, from where you can call a function to check if both the values are same..

```
compare();
$("#totalItems,#enteredItems").keyup(function() {
    compare();
});
function compare() {
    if ($("#totalItems").val() == $("#enteredItems").val()) {
        $("#hideThis").hide();
    } else {
        $("#hideThis").show();
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gh812x8/7/)

Comment: I suggest you to use toggle, instead of hide.

Comment: @Alp how do you use toggle in this context?

Comment: remove else branch and rename .hide() to toggle().

Comment: Actually, you are right. My first response was like a reflex response. As I thought about it, you are right. =] Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gh812x8/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var webpart_ID = 'hideThis';
    var FieldA_id = 'totalItems';
    var FieldB_id = 'enteredItems';
    if ($('#' + FieldA_id).val() === $('#' + FieldB_id).val()) 
        $('#' + webpart_ID).hide();
    else 
        $('#' + webpart_ID).show();
});
```

This works.